# Multilingual Database design in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

Need a procedure in SQL for translate a datatable in English to Arabic .I am having English table which is having category ID ,Code etc upto 25 columns in the SQL Database.We want to translate this table to arabic when user opts for Arabic .So  need a procedure to convert this English table to Arabic.Do i want to use google translator for this case . Then how will it  is linked with database .
Please reply with an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can check these two links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc295829(v=SQL.90).aspx

Here is a piece of code you can use as example:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs
(
   job_id  smallint
       IDENTITY(1,1)
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   job_desc varchar(50)
     COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS
     NOT NULL
    DEFAULT 'New Position - title not formalized yet',
```

)

Comment: Thank you but is it possible in sql server 2005 .

Comment: Yes collation to arabic is present in SQL 2008. Chk this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx

Comment: I want to translate the english table to arabic .Is it possible ,then how .Please help